# Need help findind function such as $f(a) = c$ and $f(c) = a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I haven't practiced algebra for ages and it seems I have issues with basic algebraic problem. So I need to find a function such as $f(a) = c$ and $f(c) = a$
As I understand we can do it with the function of a line. E.g
$$ c = ma + b$$ 
$$ a = mc + b$$

But now I am confused on what to do next. I need to solve for $m$ and $b$ right?

$$c - a = ma - mc$$
$$c - a = m(a - c)$$
$$m = \frac{c - a}{a - c}$$

And then $b$
$$c = \frac{c - a}{a - c} \times a + b$$
$$b = c - \frac{c - a}{a - c} \times a$$

And now I am stuck. What should I do next?

Comment: Helps if you simplify  $\frac {c-a}{a-c}$

Comment: You did everything right, you just seem to have forgotten *why* you are doing this. The idea is to search for a linear function $f$ with the ansatz $f(x)=mx+b$ and you need to find $m$ and $b$ with the help of the two conditions $f(a)=c$ and $f(c)=a$. That's what you already did. Now just plug $m$ and $b$ in the ansatz $f(x)=mx+b$ and there you have your function $f$. (Notes: 1. You need to assume $a\neq c$ otherwise you're dividing by zero. 2. $\frac{c-a}{a-c}=-\frac{a-c}{a-c}=-1$.)

Comment: "I need to solve for a and b, right?"  If my understanding is right (f(a) = c <==> f(c) = a for all possible a and c=f(a)) then you don't want to solve for a (which is a variable) but you want to solve for m and b.  If my understanding is right...

Comment: @piwi a = c is perfectly acceptable in which case f(a) = a. Or f(x) = x. (Or m = 1 and b=0).

Comment: It isn't clear whether f(a) = c and f(c) = a for *all* possible x = a and c = f(x) or whether there is just one a and one c where f(a) = f(c).  If it's just one a and c then $f(x) = (x - 1)^2$ works for a = 0 and c = 1, but not for necessarily for many others.  If it is for all possible a and c = f(c) then there are linear functions that do this as the OP is solving.  But there are others as well.  f(x) = 1/x (x $\ne$ 0) for example works as well. Finding the non-linear ones may be beyond the OP level but it's worth noting they exist.

Comment: @fleablood I was referring to his/her calculations. The case $a=c$ is easy, but needs to be treated a little bit differently or at least a small remark since dividing by $a-c$ (e.g. in the step $m=\frac{c-a}{a-c}$) equals dividing by $0$ which is neither perfect nor acceptable for me personally. More of a formality though, I agree.

Comment: @piwi I figured as much.  But it's easy for a novice to chug along and divide both sides without considerinng if they are dividing by zero.  In such a case saying "at this point you need to assume a ne c otherwise you're dividing by zero" is a teensy bit misleading as a novice will interpret that as a = c is impossible.  More honest is to say "in dividing by a-c you are making an assumption that a ne c, you must also consider the case where a = c" it's a minor point and pretty obvious but to a novice these things get very confusing.

Comment: @fleablood I meant exactly what you said in your last sentence. I tried to keep it short and simple and not make a big deal out of something that just is not. But probably I've been too lazy here. Thanks for the remark, acknowledged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solvable without any fancy algebra. Is there something wrong with

$$f(x)=a+c-x$$

or perhaps, if $a$ and $c$ are non-zero,

$$f(x)=\frac{ac}x$$
?

---

Here's one way to find a suitable linear function with algebra:

Substituting the expression for $c$ in $c=ma+b$ into the equation $a=mc+b$ we get

$$\begin{align}
a &= m(ma+b)+b \\
a &= m^2a+mb+b \\
0 &= (m^2-1)a+(m+1)b
\end{align}$$

Remember that $a$ is the unknown variable here, so the right-hand side is a polynomial in $a$. For that equation to hold for all $a$, the coefficients must be zero and we must have

$$m^2-1=0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (m+1)b=0$$

Solving the first gives $m=\pm 1$. If $m=1$ then the second gives $b=0$, so the function is $f(x)=x$. This does not work and is an extraneous solution.

If $m=-1$ then any $b$ will satisfy the second. We get the function $f(x)=-x+b$, and substituting $x=a,f(a)=c$ or $x=c,f(c)=a$ shows that $b=a+c$, giving us the final answer

> $$f(x)=-x+a+c$$

which is the same solution I gave earlier.

Comment: That is true. But I wanted to derive it though the system of linear functions for sake of practicing algebra :)

Comment: Could you help me to derive it though the system of linear equations please

Comment: These answers assume a and c are a single pair where f(a) = c and f(c) = a but f(x) = y does not necessarily mean f(y) = x.  I'm still not sure what the OP means be f(a) = c and f(c) = a.  I'm inclined to believe that it must mean for *all* a and c, because to do it for just a single a and c seems.... pointless. [You can define f(x) = 0 if x doens't equal a or c, f(c) =a  and f(c) = a.  That's perfectly well defined function.

Comment: But then f(x) = a + c -x isn't well defined because a and c don't have constant values.

Comment: @fleablood: It seemed clear to me that the OP wants a *linear* equation that has a particular form that will work for all distinct pairs $a,c$ of real numbers. My answer uses that interpretation. It makes no assumption on $a$ at all, and in fact my "coefficients must be zero" paragraph uses the fact that the equations must work for all $a$. You are right that different pairs $a,c$ need different linear functions, but the *form* of the function can stay the same. In fact, for a given $a,c$ this is the only linear function that satisfies his requirements. (This comment was edited.)

Comment: But if a and c meant "one specific instance" then a + b - x and ab/x would work.  But you have to set such a and b first.  Which could be set to anything.  But it wasn't clear to me that the a and b in "a + b -x" were constants when the stipulation f(a) = c and f(c) = a were not.

Comment: @fleablood: Again, that seemed clear to me, but I now see there is some ambiguity in the OP. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That is great. Thank you! The only confusing part is "Remember that a
is the unknown variable here, so the right-hand side is a polynomial in a". I did not understand this very well

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=c \frac{x-c}{a-c}+a \frac{x-a}{c-a}$$ should do the job.

You're right that a linear function will work. But then you should look at a general linear function $y=ux+v$ and write $$\begin{cases} c=ua+v\\
a=uc+v
\end{cases}$$ and solve the system to find $(u,v)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well... If your trying to find $f(c)=x, f(x)=c$, then we have:$$f(c)=x$$$$c=f^{-1}(x), c=f(x)$$$$f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$$This means $f(x)$ and its inverse are both the same.  This $f(x)$ could be anything.  In particular, note that when drawing a line along $g(x)=x$ and reflecting $f(x)$ across that line, nothing happens.  Also, the simplest answer to your question is $f(x)=x$.  Other solutions might include$$e^{ln(x+a)}-a$$$$\sqrt{x^2+a}-a$$

or even
-------$$g(f(f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))$$Which is why I say you should just leave it at $f(x)=x$.

Further more, looking upon linear functions, the following solution is noted:$$f(x)=-x+b,$$where $b$ is any number.  This is because flipping this across $g(x)=x)$ results in the same solution.

A second linear function is also noted, as $f(x)=x$ is the line of reflection and therefore doesn't change after you reflect it.

I recommend looking at most of this stuff visually in a graphing calculator if you want to see the cool flippings and stuff.  Desmos Graphing Calculator is cool because you can switch your x and y variables most of the time and it will redo the graph for you.  If switching the x and y variables yields the same image, then that function is a possible solution to your questions.